# fatal error: Index out of range when retrieving data from Firebase to add to a Swift array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am encountering the error "Index out of range" when retrieving data from Firebase 3.0 and trying to add it to a Swift array. My intent is that when the array is empty while the data is being retrieved from the Firebase real time database asynchronously the view should render displaying each label as "Not Selected". Any input on how to best do this will be greatly appreciated.

**Firebase hierarchy:**

- service_history

  - uid

    - auto id

      - label1Selected
      - label2Selected
      - label3Selected
      - label4Selected
      - label5Selected
      - label6Selected
      - label7Selected
      - etc

**Below is the View Controller code:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ServiceHistoryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //Vars
    var orderHistoryArray = [ServiceOrder]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Hide navigation bar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

        startSynchronizingServiceHistory()
    }

    func startSynchronizingServiceHistory() {

        var serviceOrder = ServiceOrder()

        //Retrieve Service History for a given UID
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("service_history").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            self.orderHistoryArray = []

            if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                for snap in snapshots {
                    if let postDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        serviceOrder = ServiceOrder(key: key, dictionary: postDictionary)
                        //Populate array
                        self.orderHistoryArray.append(serviceOrder)
                    }
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }){ (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: Hide status bar
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            //return orderHistoryArray.count
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customSummaryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SummaryCustomTableViewCell

        cell.serviceOrderSummaryLabel.text = "SERVICE ORDER SUMMARY"
        cell.dateLabel.text = "Created:"

        if (orderHistoryArray[1].createdTimestamp.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.date.text = orderHistoryArray[0].createdTimestamp
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[1].plumbingLeakEmergencyChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.date.text = "Label 1 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[2].overflowingDrainEmergencyChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 2 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[3].drainStoppageEmergencyChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 3 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[4].fixturesInstallationChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 4 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[5].waterHeaterInstallationChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 5 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[6].dishwasherInstallationChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 6 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[7].garbageDisposalInstallationChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 7 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[8].iceMakerSupplyLinesInstallationChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 8 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[9].additionalHoseBibsInstallationChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 9 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[10].fixturesRepairChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 10 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[11].waterHeaterRepairChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 11 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[12].drainCleaningServiceChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 12 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[13].waterHeaterCleanOutServiceChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 13 selected"
        }
        if (orderHistoryArray[14].leakDetectionServiceChecked.isEmpty) {
            cell.date.text = "Not selected"
        } else {
            cell.label1.text = "Label 14 selected"
        }
        cell.more.text = "More..."

        return cell

    }

}
```

**Below is the table view I am trying to render:**
[image]

Comment: Why is return orderHistoryArray.count commented out in number of rows for section?

Comment: You'll need *let key = snap.key as String*. That won't fix the issue it's just a good thing to do.

Comment: As far as populating the array and having Not Selected in the empty fields... Start with creating an array with 14 indexes and fill each with Not Selected - this will populate the UI (which has 14 slots) with 14 Not Selected strings. Then, in your observe block, *insert* each item at the 0th element of the array instead of appending them, which would cause the 14 Not Selected to move down one index. That way, you will populate from the top down. You'll need to deal with however many are needed to make the UI look right.

Comment: Thanks Amloelxer! I updated my code to return 1 or the array count in number of rows section depending on whether the count was 0 or higher.

Comment: Thanks Jay! I also updated the key to specify as String. In addition, I am addressed your suggestion to prefill the array with "Not Selected" by instead modifying my tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath) to also check in each if statement whether the array count is 0 or the given value is empty, to avoid the error when the array is empty.

Comment: Making these changes fixed my issue. I am now able to see what I want on the view, although I need to modify some things with the layout. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way I am also checking the array count to do an insert or append to the array depending on the count which was definitely the reason for at least one of the "Index out of range" errors I encountered while fixing the code. //Populate array
                        if (self.orderHistoryArray.count != 0) {
                            self.orderHistoryArray.append(serviceOrder)
                        } else {
                            self.orderHistoryArray.insert(serviceOrder, atIndex: 0)
                        }